# Viewcontroller top is hidden under Navigation Controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

The first time i load my HomeViewController among other ViewControllers i save it in appDelegate as `var savedHomeController:HomeViewController?`

My issue is when i try to load the saved controller the top of it gets hidden under the NavigationController.

It would be great to have suggestions to resolve this

Comment: Need more info:

1. Does the HomeViewController have any scrollViews or any subclass of scrollView like tableview
2. How are you loading the saved controller

Comment: I fixed it. had to set self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent to false